# API method returning an object containing a Dictionary object not returning a response body

Tags: c#, visual-studio, api, dictionary, .net-core

I have an API controller method which returns an object as Json.
When I call this endpoint, I receive back the headers for the call but no body.

Looking through the object I commented out all the fields and then reintroduced them one by one, when I reintroduced the Dictionary field...

```
Dictionary<int, string> CountryCollection {get; set;}
```

The controller method stopped returning the body response.

Thinking maybe it was something about that particular model, I created a new temporary model containing the same dictionary field, again the controller method refused to return a body response.

The project is dotnet core 2.2

No errors are thrown.

Comment: I cannot find document for 2.2, but the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-supported-collection-types?pivots=dotnet-core-3-1#supported-key-types) for 3.1 says _"Non-string keys for Dictionary and SortedList types are not supported in .NET Core 3.1."_,

Comment: I didn't put this in the OP as I didn't think it added anything of value. The live version of this API already includes this object and has done for months.
The local version was also working in the last couple of days and has not been changed in the interim.
I also have another API that returns the same object (Its in a library).

Comment: Hello, the reason may be that there is a problem with the request response header setting when requesting the controller, resulting in a problem with the returned data.

Comment: @Housheng-MSFT Thanks for the suggestion, would you mind elaborating? or could you point me in the direction of how to investigate this?